# How to import files from other folders

Tags: python-3.x

### Introduction

I am using Python 3.9. I have seen quite a few answers online but I am struggling to make it work for me.

I saw that you can set default PYTHONPATH (`PYTHONPATH=. python app/models/TestModel.py`) but it sounds very hacky and I don't see how that would work should other devs try to use the code...

As someone who comes from a world of composer and node, I was expecting files to be pulled from a route dir but there seem to be some magic in the background that I am missing.

### Issue

I have the following dir structure:

- /app/models/TestModel.py
- /modules/commons/models/BaseModel.py

Within BaseModel.py I print hello world:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Within TestModel.py I am trying to import my BaseModel

```
import modules.commons.models.BaseModel
```

The output if I am to call `TestModel.py` via CLI is below:

```
import modules.commons.models.BaseModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

Comment: Could you add the full structure of your package?

Comment: that's is the full tree structure. I have initiated venv if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `python -m app.models.TestModel` from the top of your package.  In this case, python adds the current directory to the `sys.path`.

When you run `python app/models/TestModel.py`, python assumes `app/models` is the top of your package and adds `./app/models` to `sys.path`.

Alternatively, you can put all your main entry points at the top level.

Comment: by putting main entry points at the top level you mean moving files to the root folder?

Comment: Not moving them, but placing entry points for modules used by others.  For example, putting `import app.server.server_main; app.server.server_main.main()` in top level `server.py`.  I would not do that for test code, though.  This approach will make it easier for users of your package.